# Why don't these string operations in shell work?

Tags: shell

I want to get a specific word in a string, so my code is like this:

```
#!/bin/env bash
str="ovsdb-server is running with pid 28663 ovs-vswitchdm is running with pid 29121 ovs-vswitchd is running with pid 28679"
str2=$(echo $str)
res=${str2##ovs-vswitchd}
echo $res
pos=$(expr index "$str" "ovs-vswitchd")
echo $pos
```

But the result is:

```
ovsdb-server is running with pid 28663 ovs-vswitchdm is running with pid 29121 ovs-vswitchd is running with pid 28679
1
```

I don't know why. As in my mind, I want to get "*is running with pid 28679*" and then get *28679*, but I don't know why the operations on strings do not work, please help me...

Comment: Off-topic: Use quotes when you use `echo`, like `echo "${res}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is mostly correct, excepting a few bits:

1. *Remove longest matching prefix pattern* `##` needs a `*` to match the characters in `$str2` *before* the string "*ovs-vswitchd*".

   Change:

   `res=${str2##ovs-vswitchd}` to

   `res=${str2##*ovs-vswitchd}`.
2. `expr index` returns a number that's never more than the length of the string, it does not return a substring.

   Change:

   `pos=$(expr index "$str" "ovs-vswitchd")` to

   `pos=${res##*pid }`.

Output:

```
is running with pid 28679
28679
```

Comment: `pos=${res##*pid }` will delete the additional space.